# material sidebar component not rendering

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using the material design components for Angular 4 - specifically the sidenav: https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

I've followed the example in the overview tab (and even looked at the plunkr), however in my Angular application, if I add the md-sidenav tag, nothing renders on the application. If i remove the `md-sidenav` tag whilst still keeping the container tag, then the buttons render (see below).

```
<md-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <!--<md-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav">-->
    <!--Jolly good!-->
  <!--</md-sidenav>-->

  <div class="example-sidenav-content">
    <button type="button" md-button (click)="sidenav.open()">
      Open sidenav
    </button>
  </div>

</md-sidenav-container>
```

If I un-comment the `md-sidenav` tag then nothing inside the `md-sidenav-container` is visible i.e. the page is blank.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You get any error in browser console? Can you replicate in plunker?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao no errors in browser console. I'm not sure how to replicate it in plunker.

Comment: Did you important `MatSidenavModule` into your module?

Comment: Yes i did import that

Comment: `<md-sidenav-container>` can you make sure this has been rendered in browser by inspecting it?

Comment: The container does get rendered, but when i put `md-sidenav` inside the container, it doesn't render.